# Angularjs auto calculate from 2 input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I will calculate the total of 2 input fields ie price and quantity. The programming language I use AngularJs include from the ionic framework.

My controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.a = 0;
      $scope.b = 0;
      $scope.c = $scope.a * $scope.b;
    })
```

My form.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="Kalkulator">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Price</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="a">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Qty</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Total</span>
        <input type="text" value="{{ c | currency:'Rp ' }}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Notice :

Price = 5000

Qty = 2

When I write {{ a*b }}, it is quite possible to print = Rp 10,000.00.
but I want the all process done through on the controller.

So, what script should I write in the controller to print the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-change` directive to watch changes and make sum

```
<ion-view view-title="Kalkulator">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Price</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="a" ng-change="calculate()">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Qty</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b" ng-change="calculate()>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Total</span>
        <input type="text" value="{{ c | currency:'Rp ' }}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

in controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.a = 0;
      $scope.b = 0;
      $scope.c = $scope.a * $scope.b;
      $scope.calculate = function(){
          $scope.c = $scope.a * $scope.b
      }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-keyup or ng-change function on both 'a' and 'b' fields inputs and call same function on both keyup event and put this code in that function like this.

```
$scope.mykeyupfun = function(){$scope.c = $scope.a * $scope.b;}
```